# Declaring a variable and setting its value from a SELECT query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

In SQL Server we can use this:

```
DECLARE @variable INT;
SELECT @variable= mycolumn from myTable;
```

How can I do the same in Oracle? I'm currently attempting the following:

```
DECLARE COMPID VARCHAR2(20);
SELECT companyid INTO COMPID from app where appid='90' and rownum=1;
```

Why this is not **working**?

[image]

Comment: Any idea how this can work for types as objects?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

[SELECT INTO](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm)

```
DECLARE
   the_variable NUMBER;

BEGIN
   SELECT my_column INTO the_variable FROM my_table;
END;
```

Make sure that the query only returns a single row:

> By default, a SELECT INTO statement must return only one row. Otherwise, PL/SQL raises the predefined exception TOO_MANY_ROWS and the values of the variables in the INTO clause are undefined. Make sure your WHERE clause is specific enough to only match one row
>
> If no rows are returned, PL/SQL raises NO_DATA_FOUND. You can guard against this exception by selecting the result of an aggregate function, such as COUNT(*) or AVG(), where practical. These functions are guaranteed to return a single value, even if no rows match the condition.
>
> A SELECT ... BULK COLLECT INTO statement can return multiple rows. You must set up collection variables to hold the results. You can declare associative arrays or nested tables that grow as needed to hold the entire result set.
>
> The implicit cursor SQL and its attributes %NOTFOUND, %FOUND, %ROWCOUNT, and %ISOPEN provide information about the execution of a SELECT INTO statement.

Comment: DECLARE COMPID VARCHAR2(20);
SELECT companyid INTO COMPID from sasapplication   where appid='90' and rownum=1; Can you tell why this sql is throwing error

Comment: It should be noted that `SELECT my_column INTO the_variable FROM my_table` will inherently bring back `too many rows` if the table has more than one row.  While obvious to some, it should simply indicate that a `WHERE` condition should be supplied, and also that a `the_variable :=` is not necessary, that the statement you gave automatically assigns the value to the variable.  I was tripped up and still using that part and getting all kinds of other errors before I removed that from my query.

Answer (score 8):

Not entirely sure what you are after but in PL/SQL you would simply

```
DECLARE
  v_variable INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT mycolumn
    INTO v_variable
    FROM myTable;
END;
```

Ollie.

Comment: As @Thilo states, there is more to consider around just this specific synatx. A little more info on what you're trying to achieve would enable us to tailor a better method for populating your variable.

Answer (score 8):

One Additional point:

When you are converting from `tsql` to `plsql` you have to worry about `no_data_found` exception

```
DECLARE
   v_var NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT clmn INTO v_var FROM tbl;
Exception when no_data_found then v_var := null; --what ever handle the exception.
END;
```

In `tsql` if `no data found` then the variable will be `null` but no `exception`

Answer (score 0):

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

if you don't specify the exact record by using where condition, you will get the above exception

```
DECLARE
     ID NUMBER;
BEGIN
     select eid into id from employee where salary=26500;
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(ID);
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

For storing a single row output into a variable from the select into query :

declare v_username varchare(20);
SELECT username into v_username FROM users WHERE user_id = '7';

this will store the value of a single record into the variable v_username.

---

For storing multiple rows output into a variable from the select into query :

you have to use listagg function. listagg concatenate the resultant rows of a coloumn into a single coloumn and also to differentiate them you can use a special symbol. 
use the query as below 
SELECT listagg(username || ',' ) within group (order by username) into v_username FROM users;