# Oracle Trigger causing invalid sql statement error

Tags: oracle, triggers

So I am trying to build a trigger to maintain data consistency between two tables. My ideal trigger should look something like this (it's probably not correct, I haven't been able to properly debug it yet):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salesFragmentGreaterThan
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON sales
FOR EACH ROW WHEN (sale_price >= 5000000)
DECLARE
BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
    INSERT INTO greaterThanFiveMillionFragment 
        VALUES (sales_seq.curval, :NEW.sales_date, :NEW.sale_type, :NEW.reserved_price, :NEW.sale_price, :NEW.deposit, 
            :NEW.balance, :NEW.buyer_id, :NEW.property_id);

ELSEIF DELETING THEN
    DELETE FROM greaterThanFiveMillionFragment
        WHERE greaterThanFiveMillionFragment.sales_id = :new.sales_id;

ELSEIF UPDATING THEN
    UPDATE greaterThanFiveMillionFragment
        SET :old.sales_date = :new.sales_date, :old.sale_type = :new.sale_type, :old.reserved_price = :new.reserved_price, :old.sale_price = :new.sale_price,
            :old.deposit = :new.deposit, :old.balance = :new.balance, :old.buyer_id = :new.buyer_id, :old.property_id = :new.property_id
                WHERE :old.sales_id = :newsales_id;
END IF;
/
```

This throws a series of invalid sql statement errors. I began removing code to find out which part was causing this until I got down to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salesFragmentGreaterThan
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON sales
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN (new.sale_price >= 5000000)
DECLARE
BEGIN
select sales_id from sales;
END;
/
```

This throws an invalid sql error.
The only way I can get a trigger to compile is if there is literally nothing inside the BEGIN - END block.

What am I doing wrong?

This question was marked as a duplicate and I have been directed here:
[Declaring a variable and setting its value from a SELECT query in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553901/declaring-a-variable-and-setting-its-value-from-a-select-query-in-oracle)

I am afraid I don't understand how that question relaters to mine however. The issue I am having is that I can't seem to put any code inside my BEGIN block without the compiler declaring it as an invalid SQL statement.

Comment: It is an invalid SQL statement; you have to select the data into a variable, as described in the linked question.

Comment: So it turns out I actually had to begin my trigger with **DELIMITER //**