# Oracle variable from select statement is empty value

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

In Oracle SQL statement I need to assign variable value from Select Statement. I am doing it according to line documentation but the variable value is empty.

In SQL server the following is what I need to do.

```
DECLARE @variable INT;
SELECT @variable= mycolumn from myTable;
```

In Oracle here is the output and query that I am having problem with. I am using Toad client.
My goal is to use the variable value as part of a query.

Here is a simple example intended use.

SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DateField >= :varCurrMoDateBeg

[image]

```
DECLARE
   varCurrMoDateBeg DATE;
   varCurrMoDateEnd DATE;

BEGIN 

    SELECT MONTH_BEG_DATE INTO varCurrMoDateBeg FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            CALENDAR.MONTH_BEG_DATE MONTH_BEG_DATE
        FROM 
            CALENDAR
        WHERE
            CALENDAR.CAL_TYPE='M' 
            AND (sysdate) BETWEEN CALENDAR.MONTH_BEG_DATE AND CALENDAR.MONTH_END_DATE 
        ) ;
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(varCurrMoDateBeg);
    SELECT MONTH_END_DATE INTO varCurrMoDateEnd FROM 
        (
        SELECT 
            CALENDAR.MONTH_END_DATE MONTH_END_DATE
        FROM 
            CALENDAR
        WHERE
            CALENDAR.CAL_TYPE='M' 
            AND (sysdate) BETWEEN CALENDAR.MONTH_BEG_DATE AND CALENDAR.MONTH_END_DATE 
        );
        --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(varCurrMoDateEnd);
    
END;

SELECT :varCurrMoDateBeg, :varCurrMoDateEnd from dual;
```

Online sources:

SELECT INTO Statement
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems045.htm

plsql - Declaring a variable and setting its value from a SELECT query in Oracle - Stack Overflow
[Declaring a variable and setting its value from a SELECT query in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553901/declaring-a-variable-and-setting-its-value-from-a-select-query-in-oracle)

PL/SQL SELECT INTO Statement By Practice Examples
https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/plsql-select-into/

Oracle Tutorials - Assign Query Results to Variables
http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/oracle/PL-SQL-Assign-Query-Results-to-Variables.html

Comment: Did you not get any answer from these links you have provided ? You are using a pl/sql anonymous block and the scope of the variable ends with `end` keyword. What are you trying to do it with the last query which obviously will give you null values.

Comment: To get a value out of your anonymous block, using bind variables, you would need to use `SELECT MONTH_BEG_DATE INTO :varCurrMoDateBeg`, with colon in the variable name. This would also require creating the bind variable elsewhere (tool specific). If all you want to do is see that this works, use a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` in your block to show your local variable values.

Comment: @TadHarrison I want to use the variable in a a SELECT statement as I explained in the post -- `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DateField >= :varCurrMoDateBeg`. Can you provide answer how to get value out of the anonymous block? The query will be used to create a data set in SSRS report.

Comment: [Using Bind Variables](http://dev.toadfordataanalyst.com/webhelp/Content/Editor/Set_Bind_Variables.htm) in Toad

Comment: I believe you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of  differences between T-SQL and PL/SQL. In T-SQL you can return sets of data by using select statements  within the T-SQL. Oracle does not permit this. The closest you can come to this in Oracle is with a pipeline function, While not difficult, pipeline functions take a bit of doing to set up, and can be expensive performance wise. Even with that, PL/SQL is not designed to be interactive like T-SQL is. I have used both languages, there are times I wish PL/SQL were interpretive like T-SQL, there are other times  I'm glad its not.

Comment: @BrianLeach , Thanks for the explanation. Can you recommend a good reading or reference explaining the difference between TSQL and PLSQL. If you could put that in an answer I believe that would be the accepted answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Using Toad, a small example

```
declare
v_var date;
v_bind date :=to_date('01.01.2020','DD.MM.YYYY');
v_stm varchar2(4000);
v_counter pls_integer;
begin
select sysdate into v_var from dual ;
dbms_output.put_line(v_var);
execute immediate ' select sysdate from dual ' into v_var ;
dbms_output.put_line(v_var);
-- with bind  
v_stm :=  ' select count(*) from dba_objects where created > :1 '  ;
execute immediate v_stm into  v_counter using  v_bind;
dbms_output.put_line(v_counter);
end;
/
```

[image]

When I ran this code

[image]

As you can see, it is a very easy piece of code that shows how to use bind variables in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a function for each of the dates you want to use outside of your current PL/SQL block.  Here is a rough example to demonstrate how that could be made to work.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION varCurrMoDateBeg
```

RETURN DATE
AS
dt_Work         DATE;
BEGIN
-- Replace this with your query
SELECT SYSDATE INTO dt_Work FROM dual;

```
RETURN dt_Work;
```

END varCurrMoDateBeg;
/

```
SELECT varCurrMoDateBeg FROM dual;
```