# Error code PLS-00103 when I want create trigger in Oracle19C

Tags: triggers, oracle19c

I have `table1`,`table2` in Oracle19C:

Table1:

```
id  name    ranking energy   
-------------------------------
222    tom      15      f            
333    sara     11      f    
333    sara     2       a      
111    jhon     4       h       
111    jhon     16      f    
333    sara     13      g    
222    tom      12      j
```

And `table2`:

```
id  name    ranking
-------------------
111 jhon    2
222 tom     1
333 sara    0
```

I want for any row insert to table1 automatically update the column `ranking` in table2 and if the `id` does not exist in table2, insert the row in table2.

I use below code but not work:

```
create  TRIGGER   Table1Trigger    AFTER INSERT ON  Table1   for EACH ROW


BEGIN 
  
        IF  :new.id in ( SELECT id    FROM Table2 WHERE id=:new.id)    THEN 
                UPDATE table2    SET ranking = :new.ranking    WHERE id = :new.id;
         
        else   
                insert into  Table2 (id,name,ranking )  VALUES( :new.id,:new.name,:new.ranking   )
                 
        END IF;
END
```

I get this error:`PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     if ...`

Question 2:

If the number of rows inserted in table1 is high (100 rows per second), does using `:new.id in ( SELECT id    FROM Table2 WHERE id=:new.id)` slow down the inserting operation on table1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem `PLS-00103:` was for `;`. You must put `;` at the end of the line for `IF`, `ELSE` and `END`.

More information about `DECLARE` use [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7553941/12780274).

Note: I use `ROWNUM <2` because prevent full scan table2, When find first row return count rows(always is 1).

```
create  TRIGGER   Table1Trigger    AFTER INSERT ON  Table1   for EACH ROW

DECLARE    vCheckValue number;

BEGIN 
        SELECT count(*) into vCheckValue FROM Table2 WHERE id=:new.id AND ROWNUM <2;  
        IF   ( vCheckValue >0)    THEN 
                UPDATE table2    SET ranking = :new.ranking    WHERE id = :new.id;
         
        else   
                insert into  Table2 (id,name,ranking )  VALUES( :new.id,:new.name,:new.ranking   );
                 
        END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You can rather add an index(presumably a unique index) on `id` column, and get rid of `ROWNUM<2`. Btw, you can use a MERGE statement rather than using UPDATE and INSERT individually.